# Fetching different username registed in Users table and saving it as foreign key using formset

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am saving a dynamic form having formset as below:-

**forms.py**

```
AuthorFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Author,
    fields=('title','content','due_date','author' ),
    extra=1,
    widgets={'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Enter Author Name here'}),
            'content': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Description'}),
            'due_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Date'}),
            'author': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control author-input',
            'placeholder': 'Participants'
        }),
```

One of the fields 'author', I am using an autocompletemodel for fetching name of users from User table.
In my models.py I am saving author as the foreign key in Author table.
    class Author(models.Model):

```
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'author'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username
```

However on debugging I found that the formset object that is returned in the POST request says **'id': 'none'** for author field. I think 'author' input field is only accepting userId and not username. 
I am new to django and I donot know how to save **username** from **userId** from User model.
Please point me in the right direction.

**Views.py**

```
def create_book_with_authors(request):
    template_name = 'store/create_with_author.html'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        formset = AuthorFormset(request.GET or None)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AuthorFormset(request.POST) 
        if formset.is_valid(): # Error saying that formset is not valid
            for form in formset:
                # so that `book` instance can be attached.
                author = form.save(commit=False)
                author.save()
            return redirect('mom:home')
    return render(request, template_name, {'formset': formset})
```

Comment: Please post your view.

Comment: added please check.

Answer (score 0):

I think since author is a ForeignKey you will have to get the actual user instance using the value of the TextInput, and then save that instance as the value instead. Try:

```
 if formset.is_valid(): # Error saying that formset is not valid
     for form in formset:
         # so that `book` instance can be attached.
         author = form.save(commit=False)
         a = Author.objects.get(username=author.author) # Or however you get the unique author
         author.author = a
         author.save()
```

Comment: actually problem was something different. In my template I didnot handle the hidden field form.id , that is why it was giving an error

Comment: I have a question to ask, how to generate and empty formset whenever I load the view because according ot this view.py , Everytime i open the form page. data already submitted is getting loaded??